# App not installing from Mac App Store

Tags: applications, imac, mac-appstore, install, games

Ive just got a brand new iMac and have purchased a game (BioShock Infinite) from the Mac App Store.

For some reason the download failed halfway through so I tried again from the Purchases page of the app store. However it fails again immediately.

After trying that a few times I removed it from the Purchases page and then searched for it again, back in the app store. I clicked Buy again and it advised me that it was already purchased and would download again. But the same error occurs.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted Mac altogether. Seems to have worked